# Sorting by name attribute using XSL style sheet

Tags: xslt, transformation

I have an XML file that has many nested elements of the same type. I want to be able to sort them by the name attribute value. Here is an example of the file

```
 <configurations>
    <configuration xmlns="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" name="managed">
        <configuration name="tracking-component">
            <configuration name="disks"/>
            <configuration name="cycles"/>
        </configuration>
        <configuration name="network-component" class="singular">
            <configuration name="data-component"/>
            <configuration name="node"/>
            <configuration name="modal"/>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
</configurations>
```

The goal is to have the above file to be sorted like this:

```
<configurations>
    <configuration xmlns="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" name="managed">
        <configuration name="tracking-component" class="singular">
            <configuration name="data-component"/>
            <configuration name="modal"/>
            <configuration name="node"/>
        </configuration>
        <configuration name="network-component">
            <configuration name="disks"/>
            <configuration name="cycles"/>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
</configurations>
```

I tried this stylesheet, but it did not output anything:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'Configuration']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/@name">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what I am trying to produce:

```
<configurations>
    <configuration xmlns="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" name="managed">
        <configuration name="network" class="singular">
            <configuration name="data-component"/>      
            <configuration name="modal"/>
            <configuration name="node"/>
        </configuration>
        <configuration name="tracking-component">
            <configuration name="cycles"/>
            <configuration name="disks"/>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
</configurations>
```

The `network-component` attribute now appears before the `tracking-component` attribute in the right alphabetical order. The configuration attributes in `network-component` and `tracking-component` are also sorted in alphabetical order.

Please help.

Comment: I improved indenting of your XML sections and sanitized your XSLT section by adding a `>` to the end of the processing-instruction `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:configuration">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:configuration">
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**:

1. XML is case-sensitive: `Configuration` does not equal `configuration`;
2. The proper way to handle elements in a namespace is by using a prefix as shown - not by  ignoring the namespace by using the local name only;
3. The result is different from the one shown in your question - but I believe it is correct nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It prints the contents but does not sort them by name.

Comment: The problem is that the outer configuration that contain the parent configuration elements are written together with the inner child ones, resulting in  a flattened structure.  Even though the inner ones are sorted, the sorting is lost because the parent elements are written as well.

Comment: @BreenDeen No, that is not what happens. You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb